# Fix MySQL server crash

Tags: mysql

We recently suffered a pretty severe server crash on one of our linux machines (Fedora Core 5), which has resulted in a lot of corruption of data, unfortunately the mysql database is amongst the data which has been lost.
While we were able to get the server to boot, mysql still refuses to load. The server still produces a lot of errors on startup, so I have created a new server (Ubuntu 8.10) and copied the mysql directory across to this - but again mysql will not start.

Attached is a dump of the errors shown when running `mysqld --verbose`, with the `innodb_force_recovery=6` option .

Sometimes while running this check, it will pass the sanity check, while other times it will fail.

I have found plenty of articles on how to recover from a crash, but all assume that you can actually get mysql to start - which is not the case here. Additionally i have tried all `innodb_force_recovery` options, from 1-8, and none of them allow mysql to start.

Can anyone advise on how to go about recovering the data? If I browse the `ibdata1` file I can see most of the data (there appear to be a few rows missing). Are there any tools that can read the `ibdata1` file and extract data row by row?

All help greatly appreciated - as I am starting to fail my sanity check!

Comment: You probably forgot to attach the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone advise on how to go about recovering the data? If I browse the ibdata1 file I can see most of the data (there appear to be a few rows missing). Are there any tools that can read the ibdata1 file and extract data row by row?

Please don't do this... you may end up corrupting innodb data files.

It is better to follow what the error log says..

> "Please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/using-stack-trace.html and follow instructions on how to resolve the stack trace. Resolved stack trace is much more helpful in diagnosing the problem, so please do 
>   resolve it"

Just follow the steps provided in the link. Once the stack trace issue is resolved you will have the exact cause for the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Mysqldump as much as you can. Ensure you are only working in readonly mode. you don't want to corrupt the data further.

Start here: [Percona MySQL Data Recovery](https://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/innodb-data-recovery-tool:mysql-data-recovery:start)

You will want to work on a copy of the data files that is least altered since the crash. You'll need programming skills and if you don't have them then bring in a programmer.

You'll need to build Percona's recovery tools and have them customized specifically for the structure of the data you are recovering. This is where you'll benefit from programming concepts as you'll be modifying a little bit of c code. Use the existing .frm files to get the structure.

The premise is you are going to extract the data blocks from the data files to disk and then create cookie cutter tools that will run through the data blocks and export out the data.

I went through a bad crash last year when colleagues ignored monitoring alerts and a DB server ran out of disk space. It took about a day to make a plan + prep the tools and by the end of the week we had over 1000 databases back online. The only data that was unrecoverable was in tables that had extremely high write activity.